# Запрос на сервер и выборка файла из базы

Tags: c#, sql, сервер, сокет

Привет изучаю сокеты  на c# и  для практики есть такая идея.
Есть  два простеньких приложения сервер и клиент.Клиент отправляет запрос в виде строки в ответ приходит это же строка.
Я хочу  с помощью таких запросов организовать выгрузку файлу из базы.
Как я это вижу. На примере картинки.
1.Отправил запрос "Машина"
2.Сервер получил запрос "Машина". 
3.Cделал запрос

```
select * from image where name = 'Машина'
```

в базу и если картинка найдена  то вернуть ее в качестве ответа на запрос иначе вернуть ответ с ошибкой что картинки нету.
Так вот у меня есть несколько вопросов.
1.Возможно ли хранение файлов в SQL базе или использовать надо другую базу данных.
2.Как вытащить картинку из базы и отправить в качестве запроса.
Я понимаю что это будет отправлять в виде массива байтов.Но не пониманию как.
Передача будет идти как потом и надо будет использовать StreamReader или нет.Кто что нить подобное делал или имеет понятие подскажите.

**С новым годом Вас!!!**

Comment: не думали о том, что бы реализовать это в виде веб-приложения? сервер - веб-сервер, клиент - браузер?

Comment: я хочу  на c# использовать wpf

Comment: оконое приложение типа будет

Comment: даже в таком виде можно реализовать сервер как веб-вервер и общаться с ним по REST. это будет удобно, так как необходимые библиотеки уже есть.

Comment: можете ссылочку дать на информацию или подробнее описать как видите решение этой задачи

Comment: к сожалению, я не знаю си шарп на столько хорошо. вот что дал беглый поиск https://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/145178/ https://habrahabr.ru/post/164945/ https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/jj819168.aspx Описать решение в комментариях не могу. А дать его в качестве ответа нельзя, так как вопрос про другое.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: на SO принято плюсовать комментарии которые помогли

Comment: @Санитариум вот хорошая [ссылочка](http://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet_webapi/)